# Bilinear maps on smooth vectors of unitary representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, locally-convex-spaces

Let $G$ be a connected semi-simple real Lie group with finite center. Let $R_i$ ($i=1,2,3$) be unitary irreducible representations of $G$. Let $R_i^\infty$ be the corresponding representations of $G$ on smooth vectors of $R_i$, endowed with topology induced by the injection $R_i^\infty\to C^\infty(G;R_i)$, which makes them Fréchet spaces. I am interested in the space of bilinear homomorphisms
$$
H\equiv \operatorname{Hom}_G(R_1^\infty \times R_2^\infty, R_3).
$$
If I have my tensor products right, it is also
$$
H\simeq \operatorname{Hom}_G(R_1^\infty \hat\otimes R_2^\infty, R_3)
$$
where $\hat\otimes$ is the projective tensor product.

If $R_3$ appears as a direct summand in the Hilbert tensor product $R_1\otimes R_2$, then it relatively easily gives an element of $H$. I expect that this remains true, in some sense, for all representations appearing in the direct integral decomposition of $R_1\otimes R_2$. (I am not sure how one is supposed to formalize "all" and "appearing" — forgive me, I am only a physicist. I do think that the answer is not "almost all".)

On the other hand, I also think that in general there are elements in $H$ which do not arise from the tensor product $R_1\otimes R_2$, which can be seen by explicit calculations for $G=\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, although I am not completely sure that I am interpreting these calculations correctly.

So my questions is: Are there any useful characterizations of $H$? Is it understood when $H$ is finite-dimensional? What is the precise relation between $H$ and $R_1\otimes R_2$?

Comment: Are the homomorphisms just abstract vector-space homomorphisms respecting the $G$-action, or are there topologies on the spaces of smooth vectors that must be respected?  Also, do you really mean a homomorphism from the direct product, or should it be from the tensor product?

Comment: (Since you mention bilinear maps in the subject, it seems likely you do mean the source to be the tensor product.)

Comment: @LSpice I have edited the question, hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: I have also fixed a typo: I want the target space to be $R_3$, not $R_3^\infty$. The image, I believe, will always be $R_3^\infty$, but I am interested in the coarser topology coming from $R_3$.

Comment: Actually I think one can replace $R_3$ by $R_3^\infty$ in $Hom_G(R_1^\infty\hat\otimes R_2^\infty,R_3)$. This is because $V=R_1^\infty\hat\otimes R_2^\infty$ is a differentiable representation (Warner 4.4.1.10 & restrict to diagonal group), and continuous $f:V\to R_3$ maps $C^\infty(G;V)\to C^\infty(G;R_3)$ continuously.